# Pygame 2d map error

Tags: maps, python, pygame

I'm writing a Legend of Zelda like game in pygame.

I have this code for loading a map from a text file.

```
#Load maps
f = open ("map1","r")#This file is a text file containing only: 1
map01 = f.read()

terrains = [{"sprite": dirt}, {"sprite": mountian}, {"sprite": water}]

themap = [[-1 for x in range(150)] for y in range (150)]

for x in range (0,150):
    for y in range (0,150):
        themap[x][y] = terrains[map01]#if I replace map01 here with a number or random.randint(0,2) it works as expected

    for x in range (0, 150):
        for y in range (0, 150):
            screen.blit(themap[x][y]["sprite"], [x * 16, y * 16])
```

But that gives me:

```
$ python map.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "map.py", line 17, in <module>
    themap[x][y] = terrains[map01]
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Ok I'm making this a bit clearer I want to make a file called map1 that looks like this

```
1, 2, 1, 0 etc.
```

I can make a random screen with random.randint:
[image: random.randint]

and I can make it a solid texture:
[image: with solid]

but I can't figure out how to predefine a map.

Comment: While you are making a game, the question you're asking is not specific to game development. It's a general programming question. Those questions should be asked on stackoverflow.com

Comment: Now that I've figured it out does it still need to be moved. Is there something a Mod can do to move the whole question?

Comment: It appears I can't move it. You might want to check if it's possible for you to post questions on stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I managed to fix it myself so I'll go ahead and put what I got.

Instead of loading a text file I made a map_data.py file and put a two dimensional array inside. then I imported the array in my main file:

```
from map_data import map1
```

and then I changed this line to:

```
for x in range (0,150):
    for y in range (0,150):
        themap[x][y] = terrains[map1[x][y]]

                                    /\
                     I had random.randint(0, 2) here before.
```

Answer (score 4):

The `read()` function in this line:

```
map01 = f.read()
```

doesn't do any format checking to try determine what the text is.  It just returns raw bytes as a string.  You need to convert it to a number explicitly:

```
map01 = int(f.read())
```

Comment: That worked. But I can't make it like 1, 1 ,0, 0, 1 or it gives me an error. I can only use one character any idea how to fix that part?

Comment: Byte56's comment is correct, you're asking a Python programming question, not a game question.  That's better asked on SO.  Be sure to take some time going over the Python docs on reading text from files before you ask.  The SO folks will want to see that you've done some research.